# Providing the DataContext for Sparrow Chart WP8 from ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am following [this](https://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Create%20a%20Basic%20Chart&referringTitle=SparrowChart) tutorial on how to create a basic sparrow chart. Basically involves creating a ViewModel class and setting the ViewModel in the DataContext for the chart.

**The ViewModel:**

```
//Create a model
public class Model
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    public Model(double x,double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;           
    }      
}

// Create a ViewModel
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Collection { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        GenerateDatas();
    }
    private void GenerateDatas()
    {
        this.Collection.Add(new Model(0, 1));
        this.Collection.Add(new Model(1, 2));
        this.Collection.Add(new Model(2, 3));
        this.Collection.Add(new Model(3, 4));
    }
}
```

**The XAML:**

```
//Use the viewmodel in the Sparrow Chart
<sparrow:SparrowChart>
   <sparrow:SparrowChart.DataContext> 
          **<local:ViewModel/>**
  </sparrow:SparrowChart.DataContext>
        <sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
                <sparrow:LinearXAxis/>
        </sparrow:SparrowChart.XAxis>
        <sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
                <sparrow:LinearYAxis/>
        </sparrow:SparrowChart.YAxis>
       <sparrow:LineSeries PointsSource="{Binding Collection}" XPath="X" YPath="Y"/>
```

How do i go about defining the **local:** namespace and then include  ViewModel in it so that it works well in the DataContext?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to your window's XAML code
`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Here.Comes.Your.Namespace"`

In my case it looks like

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyProgram.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sparrow="http://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/wpf"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProgram"
        Title="My Program" Height="306" Width="736" MinWidth="680" MinHeight="440">
```

Also to actually bind collection you would use to feed data to SparrowChart, set chart's DataContext with your instance of ViewModel.

```csharp
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainWindow
{
    ViewModel myViewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ...
        myViewModel = new ViewModel();
        mySparrowChart.DataContext = myViewModel;
    }
}
```

SparrowChart's control name is `mySparrowChart` of course (
`<sparrow:SparrowChart Name="mySparrowChart">`).